# Disable all switchery with jquery onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable switchery checkboxes using jquery, on click events of a button.
I know there is a `disable()` method, but i don't know how to use it inside a function cause The problem is that i've to first retrieve all checkboxes with switchery initialized and  I don't know how.

My jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/g94gkaL7/38/

Comment: After click on `DISABLE ALL CHECKBOXES` link It `disable` all checkboxes, so what's the problem?

Comment: no. it disable only standard checkboxes. It doesn't disable switchery checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hold the reference to the created switchery items, then iterate through them and call disable.

```
 var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
 var switcheries= [];
 elems.forEach(function(html, index) {
    var switchery = new Switchery(html,{size: 'small',});
    switcheries[index] = switchery;
  });


   $("#dis").on("click", function(){

        $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", true); // works for standard input checkbox only

      // now i want to retrieve all existing swithcery to disable them
      //switchery.disable();
     switcheries.forEach(item => item.disable());

   });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g94gkaL7/39/)

Comment: This is what i'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var switcherylist = [];
$(document).ready(function() {

  //switchery
  //var checkbox = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
  var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
  elems.forEach(function(html) {
        var switchery = new Switchery(html,{size: 'small',});
      switcherylist.push(switchery);
  });

   $("#dis").on("click", function(){

        $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", true); // works for standard input checkbox only
      switcherylist.forEach(function(switchery) {
      switchery.disable();
      });
      // now i want to retrieve all existing swithcery to disable them
      //switchery.disable();

   });

});
```